# Redirect Http request to different port

Tags: java, http, servlets, routes, jetty

I have two Http Request Handler running on jetty server on two different port. One of the server is primary and the other one is secondary. In case primary crash, I want all the request of primary to be routed to secondary. Is it possible to do such thing ?

Comment: If primary crashes, then there's no way to get any other transaction there. It would be better for you to look for a [load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing))

Comment: Luigi is right, you should take a look at load balancers because the reason of the crash (JVM OOM etc.) may completely crash your entire Jetty instance not only a single handler.